# Unwrapping Blender Model results in a deformed uv map

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, export

I'm new to blender so its possible I've made a mistake, but when i tried to unwrap my model, all that appears is lines and polygons. I've tried removing doubles and manually selecting each face to make sure I hadn't selected any extra faces, but my results were the same.

Any reason why this is happening?

(The reason I was unwrapping the model was to create a texture out of the materials i had used to colour my model, and then export the texture.)
[image: The UV map isn't correct]

Comment: Welcome, MashyZ. You must learn about "seams".

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/seams.html

Comment: Like that it looks when unwrap is Reset, try to search for unwrap methods https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/index.html